# Spousal IRA: limits on what bank accounts contributions can come from?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira

My spouse is currently unemployed, and I would like to continue making contributions to her IRA using my income. I understand that these `spousal' contributions are a fairly regular form of retirement investing.

I am less clear on restrictions for sourcing these contributions. I would prefer to just transfer some additional amount of money X to my wife's checking account each month, and she would make the deposit into her IRA from there. Would this violate some condition on the contribution needing to come *directly* from me (*e.g.*, from my checking account)?

It seems bizarre that the IRS would care about this kind of distinction, but I'd rather not run afoul of a technicality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as you, or rather, your wife, qualifies for a deposit, the source doesn't matter. As an example, if my child makes more than $5500, and I'd like to help her with her IRA, I can gift her the money for the deposit. The actual funds don't need to be from her income.